# How to mock firebase.auth.UserCredential jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs

This is my current mock i want `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to return `firebase.auth.UserCredential` so i can test if it is being called or not in my `App.ts`

**App.spec.ts**

```
import myAuthenticationPlugin from 'authenticationPlugin/App'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
jest.mock('firebase/app', () => {
  return {
    auth: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    currentUser: {
      email: 'test',
      uid: '123',
      emailVerified: true
    },

    signInWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn(),
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword:jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        user:{
          sendEmailVerification:jest.fn(),
        },
      }
    }),
    initializeApp:jest.fn()
  };
});

 describe('Test for signup (email,password)',() => {

    it('createUserWithEmailAndPassword ()',async () => {  //this works
      await myAuthenticationPlugin.signup(email, password)
      expect(firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword).toBeCalledWith(email, password)
    })

    it('sendEmailVerification()',async ()=>{
      await myAuthenticationPlugin.signup(email, password)
      const userCredential= await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      if(userCredential.user!=null){
      expect(userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification).toBeCalled() //this fails as i'm not able to mock properly
      }
    })
  })
```

**App.ts**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import './Init'
const App= {
 signup: async (email, password) => {
    const userCredential = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    await userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification()
    return `Check your email for verification mail before logging in`
  },
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`app.ts`:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const App = {
  signup: async (email, password) => {
    const userCredential = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    await userCredential.user!.sendEmailVerification();
    return `Check your email for verification mail before logging in`;
  },
};
export default App;
```

`app.test.ts`:

```js
import App from './app';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const userCredentialMock = {
  user: {
    sendEmailVerification: jest.fn(),
  },
};

jest.mock('firebase/app', () => {
  return {
    auth: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn(() => userCredentialMock),
  };
});

describe('61391590', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const email = 'example@gmail.com';
    const password = '123';
    const actual = await App.signup(email, password);
    expect(actual).toEqual('Check your email for verification mail before logging in');
    expect(firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword).toBeCalledWith(email, password);
    expect(userCredentialMock.user?.sendEmailVerification).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61391590/app.test.ts (12.946s)
  61391590
    ✓ should pass (7ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 app.ts   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.863s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61391590

Comment: I had to move `const userCredentialMock` inside `jest.mock` else it was throwing an error saying 
.
.
.
.
babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The 
module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
    Invalid variable access: userCredentialMock

Comment: Also why are we resetting the mocks ? any specific reason or just as a best practice ?

Comment: Can you help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408137/mock-implementation-of-firebase-auth-methods-after-mocking-the-firebase-module

Comment: @Phil you should use prefix as mock. like mockUserCredential