# Mock fetched data with react-testing-library - still in loading state

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-testing-library

Using react hooks I am fetching some data on component mount. I set loading in state.

```
  const fetchData = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData([data?.data]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

I want to test a component with a data fetched. Here's what I tried:

```
const expectedResponse = {
  data: [{ id: 'id', name: 'name' }],
};
(fetch as jest.MockedFunction<typeof fetch>).mockResolvedValueOnce(
  new Response(JSON.stringify(expectedResponse)),
);
```

Also with `fetch-mock`:

```
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
fetchMock.restore().get(ENDPOINT, {
  data: [
    { id: 'id', name: 'name' },
  ],
});
```

in both cases data is not fetched. When I check the component's snapshot I see the Loader indicator. Looks like it is never loaded?

Any advices?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your test? You might need to wait for the request to complete before you see the changes in the DOM.

Comment: What's the test result? What does the component render? Show the code

Answer (score 0):

You should provide as much code as possible, and [ideally a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for future questions as this helps us understand better what you are trying to solve.

I don´t have any context of the test, but I assume you can be checking the snapshot synchronously, and the Promise is not being resolved before the check. You can use any of [the async methods that Testing Library provides](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/).

The async methods do polling and try to execute the queries several times until it reaches a timeout (that you can set in the Testing Library config), and if you want to know what happens after every execution, you can wrap some function inside a `waitFor` call:

```js
test('an async example', async () => {
  renderXXX();

  await waitFor(() => {
    screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL();
    expect(screen.queryByTest('just an example').toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

If it also helps, here is another tip that might help as well, regarding how to mock API requests:
[Mocking react custom hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973963/mocking-react-custom-hook/66988231#66988231)